# Binding Dictionary to GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, dictionary

I have a List of dictionary that I want to bind to a grid view in C# winform

```
public class Person { 
  Dictionary<string, object> attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes {
    get { return attributes; }
  }
}

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.Attributes.Add("name", "Ross");
person1.Attributes.Add("address", "Street 1");
persons.Add(person1);
Person person2 = new Person();
person2.Attributes.Add("name", "Tom");
person2.Attributes.Add("address", "Street 2");
persons.Add(person2);
```

So how do I use this dictionary to bind it to the grid view. Is it like below?

```
GridView1.DataSource = persons.Select(x => x.Attributes).ToList();
```

What I want is for the grid to show the strings (keys) to be the columns

e.g.

name | address

Ross | Street 1

Tom  | Street 2

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GridView1.DataSource = 
persons.Select(p => new 
{name = p.Attributes["name"], address = p.Attributes["address"]});
```

Comment: I think anonymous types is the way to go, but you need to add .ToList() to force the query to execute..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
            Person person1 = new Person();
            person1.Attributes.Add("name", "Ross");
            person1.Attributes.Add("address", "Street 1");
            persons.Add(person1);
            Person person2 = new Person();
            person2.Attributes.Add("name", "Tom");
            person2.Attributes.Add("address", "Street 2");
            persons.Add(person2);

            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> items = persons.Select(person => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(person.Attributes["name"].ToString(), person.Attributes["address"].ToString())).ToList();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = items;
```